# Restrict the space of pallet racks which where chosen by a if else function

Tags: anylogic

I have 3 pallet racks which have a capacity of 80 itself.
I would like to **restrict the area for the different pallet racks** to avoid an error when the pallet racks haven't enough space to store my pallets.
When I use a restricted area block like in my screenshot I can't restrict the space for every pallet rack, only in total.
How can I restrict the area that my pallets have to wait until space is available that I don't get an error when there isn't enough space in my racks.

[image: getmypalletrack]

[image: process]

Comment: a selectOutput block between sourcePallets and queue and make a different structure for each pallet rack... since you don't want to repeat, make a custom block that contains all your blocks from the queue to the restrictedAreaEnd

Comment: a custom block? what do you exactly mean?

Comment: and @Felipe should I use a select output 5 where I use my different conditions instead of the function?

Comment: learn how to create a custom block here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBwJtqUdhgM and yes use a selectOutput5

Comment: I did it with a custom flowchart. Thanks Felipe